# Application Insights Docker "Error retrieving data" in Portal

Tags: azure-application-insights

I deployed the Azure Application Insights Docker image as per https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-docker/ and then added the Docker tile to the App Insights blade. For one of my environments it is working fine and showing data.

For the other environment, all of those graphs are blank except a message "Error retrieving data."

I double checked the Docker command and looked at the logs for that container, nothing in there I can see to figure this out. I also restarted the container. Overall this container has been deployed for about 12 hours. Finally, I checked the status page at: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/applicationinsights-status/

I do see some data like Available Memory under "Servers" in Settings, but not sure this is the data I want.

Any troubleshooting steps people are aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I leave it to the mods if they want to remove this question given my answer. The problem resolved itself. My best guess is the issue listed here had spillover effects.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/applicationinsights-status/2016/03/16/experiencing-data-gaps-for-availability-0315-investigating/

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights for Docker currently has a *UI bug when sending Docker telemetry for AI application for the **first time***. If you sent Docker telemetry for this specific application in the past, you shouldn't have encounter this issue.

This issue will be auto-resolved after a few minutes once Docker telemetry started to be sent, and it is not related to the availability incident mentioned above.